# Python Flush Input before raw_input()

Tags: python, stdin, flush

As a php programmer (of sorts) very new to os and command line processes, I'm surprised that within python, everything a user inputs during the course of interacting with a program seems to be buffered, waiting to pour out at the first use of `raw_input` (for example).

Found some code to call prior to `raw_input` which seems to "solve" the problem on osX, although supposedly it is providing [access to windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) capabilities:

```
class FlushInput(object):

    def flush_input(self):
        try:
            import msvcrt
            while msvcrt.kbhit():
                msvcrt.getch()
        except ImportError:
            import sys, termios
            termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
```

Am I understanding correctly that stdin and stdout, stderr methods will vary between OSs?

I imagine that maybe a framework like Django has built-in methods that simplify the interactivity, but does it basically take a few lines of code just to tell python "don't accept any input until it's invited?"

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the line where you ask for tutorials and the like to prevent this from being closed as off-topic, I hope you don't mind

Comment: It's not "providing access to windows capabilities" on OS X. That part is there to make it cross platform, so it will work on windows too. On OS X, it will be an error to `import msvcrt`, so the `except` clause will run instead.

Comment: TY, Ooga. So the `try` and `except` clauses could just as well be reversed, right?

Answer (score 5):

Ahhh. If I'm understanding this correctly (and I'm sure the understanding needs much refining), the answer is that yes, `stdin, stdout, stderr`, "Standard" input, output and error streams and their handling may vary from (operating) system to system, because they are products of the OS and NOT any particular programming language.

The expectation that "telling python to ignore stdin until input is requested" would be automatic stems from an thinking of the "terminal" as if it were a typewriter. Where the goal of a typewriter is to record strings of information in a human-readable format, the goal of a terminal is to transmit information which will ultimately be converted to a machine-readable format, and to return human-readable responses.

What most of us coming to computing currently think of as a "terminal" is actually a virtual recreation of a physical machine known as a terminal which used to be the method by which data would be input to and read from a computer processor, right? And a text-editor an application that creates a virtual type-writer out of the keyboard, monitor and processing capabilities of the operating system and included libraries of programs.

An application like the mac OS terminal or even the tty we use to engage with another server via and ssh connection is actually creating a virtual terminal through which we can engage with the processor, but sending information to stdin and receiving from stdout and strerr. When the letters we type appear in the terminal screen, it is because it is being "echoed" back into the terminal window.

So there's no reason to expect that the relationship between python or any other language and a terminal, would by default block the input stream coming from a terminal.

The above code uses pythons `exception handling` to provide two alternative ways of flushing the input stream prior to some activity on behalf of the program. On OSX platform the code:

```
import sys, termios
termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
```

imports the system so we can have access to stdin, and termios, which is python's module for managing the POSIX (LINUX, UNIX) application which actually manages TWO virtual terminals  - one between itself and the user, and another between itself and the operating system. `tcflush` appears to be a function that accepts at least two parameters - the first being WHICH stream to flush - the `file descriptor` (fd), and the second being the queue to flush. I'm not sure what the difference is between the file descriptor and queue is in this case, except that maybe the fd contains data that hasn't yet been added to the queue and the queue contains data that is no longer contained in the fd.

`msvcrt` is the python module for interacting with (managing) whatever Windows version of a terminal is, and I guess `msvcrt.kbhit()` and `msvcrt.getch()` are functions for flushing it's input queue.

The UNIX and Windows calls of the function could be swapped so that rather than saying, `try:` doing it the windows way and if an `ImportError` is raised to it the UNIX was, we `try:` the UNIX way first:

```
class FlushInput(object):

    def flush_input(self):
        try:
            import sys, termios
            termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
        except ImportError:
            import msvcrt
            while msvcrt.kbhit():
                msvcrt.getch()
```

Here's [a termios introduction](https://blog.nelhage.com/2009/12/a-brief-introduction-to-termios/) that helped clarify the process.