# PyCharm does not flush input stream

Tags: python-3.x, input, pycharm

I'm doing an interface where the user needs to press "`enter`" key when he/she is ready to continue. There are few steps so this will happen few times. I want to avoid the situation where the user accidentally double-presses "`enter`" and the next phase starts too soon. In other words I want to flush the input stream every time before the "please press enter to continue" question. I'm using PyCharm 2018.3.7 (Community Edition, built July 9, 2019) in Windows 10.

Following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24582233/11199684) I built the following code.

```
import msvcrt
import time

def flush_input():
  while msvcrt.kbhit():
      aa = msvcrt.getch()
      print("(Debug flush) Discarding character >%s<" % aa)

def main():
  aa = input("Hit enter when you are ready to start.")
  n = 5;
  print("you typed >%s<" % aa)
  time.sleep(n)
  print("slept for %d seconds" % n)
  flush_input()
  bb = input("Type something and press return.")
  print("you typed >%s<" % bb)

main()
```

It works as expected in the interactive mode running from terminal without PyCharm, but does not flush anything when working from PyCharm console. How should I modify the code to make it work also in PyCharm console?

Result in interactive mode: `>>>` is the prompt. At the first question I typed `hjkl` and "enter". During the sleep I typed `dsafd` and "enter" and at final question `meh` and "enter":

```
>>> main()
Hit enter when you are ready to start.hjkl
you typed >hjkl<
slept for 5 seconds
(Debug flush) Discarding character >b'd'<
(Debug flush) Discarding character >b's'<
(Debug flush) Discarding character >b'a'<
(Debug flush) Discarding character >b'f'<
(Debug flush) Discarding character >b'd'<
(Debug flush) Discarding character >b'\r'<
Type something and press return.meh
you typed >meh<
>>>
```

Result in PyCharm console. There is no prompt. At the first question I typed `hjkl` and "enter". During the sleep I typed `dsafd` and "enter" and the final question I never got to answer:

```
Hit enter when you are ready to start.hjkl
you typed >hjkl<
dsafd
slept for 5 seconds
Type something and press return.you typed >dsafd<
```